# How to check the length of a string in Julia?

Tags: julia

I have some string which is being created programmatically as part of a GitHub action. The contents of the string are coming from an API so I don't know how long each part of the string will be. I then need to tweet the string using Twitter.jl. However, right now it errors out sometimes since the string is too long (twitter has a 280 character limit).

How can I check the length of the string in Julia to make sure it is less than 280 characters?

Comment: t’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/?_ga=2.234024286.1949022841.1631233456-1690002512.1626695629&_gac=1.118873467.1631243013.Cj0KCQjw4eaJBhDMARIsANhrQAAr9FjQp8hjie7s2gkeOGuC4H9izpdqrerj3VpLe7e9l0cnTHr_1bsaAmPYEALw_wcB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Julia has a build in `length` function which returns the length of a given string like the following example:

```
julia> a = "Hello world"
"Hello world"

julia> length(a)
11
```

Comment: This is only an approximate estimate of what Twitter would accept as `length` counts characters. The exact rules how length is calculated by Twitter is given here https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/counting-characters.

Comment: Thank you, that's a very good point, I will take a look at this.